# Context free grammar for this context free language

Tags: context-free-grammar

A context free grammar for the following language?

```
L={a^m b^n a^k|Maximum(m,n) => k}  Σ={a,b}
```

Comment: What progress have you made so far? Note that this can be expressed as a union of two languages, one with the constrains m >= k and the other with n >= k. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that language is not context-free, so can not be represented by a CFG. We can see this by using the pumping lemma for context-free languages.

Let G be a Chomsky grammar such that L(G) = L. Let j (normally called *k*) = *2^(n+1)* where *n* = the number of non-terminals in G. Let z = *uvwxy* with *|vwx|* <= j, *|vx|* > 0, and by the pumping lemma, for all i >= 0, s_i = *u(v^i)w(x^i)y* is in L. Let z = *a^j b^j+1 a^j+1*. There are several cases for choosing v and x that produce contradictions. Remember our language is {a^m b^n a^k | k = max(m,n)}.

**Case 1** *v* and *x* are both of form a*: we chose our string to be a^j b^j+1 a^j+1, so pumping up the a's will result in the string a^j+i b^j+1 a^j+1+i if v and x are from the first and second a's respectively, a^j+2i b^j+1 a^j+1 if v and x are both in the first a, or a^j b^j+1 a^j+1+2i if they're both from the second. It is apparent that all of these are contradictions, as *k* does not equal max(m,n) for a large i.

**Case 2** *v* and *x* are both of form b*: We are pumping up only the b's, which means we'll get a^j b^j+1+2i a^j+1, which is not accepted as *j+1* != *j+1+2i.*

**Case 3** *v* is of form a* and *x* is of form b*: Since *v* is before *x*, *v* is representing a number of a's in the first a section. But since we're pumping up the a's and the b's, we'll get a^j+i b^j+1+i a^j+1, so k != max(m,n) and we have a contradiction.

**Case 4** *v* is of form b* and *x* is of form a*: This doesn't provide a contradiction as we're pumping up the maximum (b^n) at the same rate as the a^k.

**Case 5** *v* contains both *a*'s and *b*'s: If we pump this up, we'll get the substring abab..ab between our a^m and b^n or the substring baba..ba between b^n and a^k, which is not accepted.

**Case 6** *x* contains both *a*'s and *b*’s: Similar to Case 6.

Proving irregularity with the pumping lemma for CFL's is very tedious, but I hope this helps!